# R squared in linear regression

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference, regression, linear-regression

How do I see that :

$\frac{(\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}))^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2}$ is always between 0 and 1?

---

where $\bar{x}=1/n *\sum(x_i)$, or the sample mean

Comment: In mathjax "\bar x" will get you $\bar x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\leq 1$ part follows from the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), where $$\sum a_i^2\sum b_i^2\geq\left(\sum a_ib_i\right)^2$$
The $\geq 0$ part is straightforward because $x^2\geq0$ for any $x$.

Comment: I am wondering is there any better or easy way to do so? (Instead of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality)?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz might be the easiest and best way. Alternatively, one can show (with tedious algebra) that the expression that you have in the OP is equivalent to $1-(SSE/SST)$ where $0 \leq SSE \leq SST$.

Comment: I C. Your comment is written in terms of R square. This is even harder to recognize.......

Comment: I prefer the ones in your solution.

Comment: Not my solution - @Lazy Lee's solution : )

Answer (score 2):

We know that $-1\leq r\leq 1.$
The given quantity is, by definition, square of the correlation coefficient. Hence, 
$$0\leq r^2=\dfrac{\left[\sum (x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y})\right]^2}{\sum (x_{i}-\bar{x})^2\sum (y_{i}-\bar{y})^2}\leq 1$$.

Comment: You say "we know that $0 \leq r \leq 1$". Two things: 1) One could have negative correlation. 2) What the OP is asking to prove is essentially what is needed to prove what you take for granted in "we know that $0 \leq r \leq 1$" (should be $-1 \leq r \leq 1$).

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Thank you for pointing the error. A typo. Thank you, once again. I have corrected that typo.